# Change the BEF slider field min/max value based on resultant nodes MAX MIN value

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a Drupal view configured for showing services list with their prices and some other fields.  I am using BEF module to filter the list of services on the front-end. Price field is using the jQuery Slider   for filter data. Now i want to set the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM limit of slider based on MAX price node and MIN price node in the list.

I have tried hook_better_exposed_filters_settings_alter(&$settings) to change the BEF field settings but is no longer working in the latest update. Any one who achieved this please help!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Never mind if the solution leads me to change in BEF module file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEF module add these options as javascript options, so you can use hook_js_alter() to override it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function MODULE_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $settings = $javascript['settings']['data'];

  foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($settings[$key]['better_exposed_filters']['slider_options']['commerce_price_amount']['max'])) {
      $settings[$key]['better_exposed_filters']['slider_options']['commerce_price_amount']['max'] = 1000;
    }
  }

  $javascript['settings']['data'] = $settings;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i think this will be a time consuming process as it will not check the filter formats and will run on all site pages. Also there is bright possibilities to produce undefined index error for "better_exposed_filters", "slider_options", "commerce_price_amount" indexes. One more thing, this is a field specific so if there is a change in view field then this will need to revise every time and need to add more code for every new field using the slider options.
Could you have any other stable solution? I never mind if the solution leads me to change in BEF module file.